# Danger/Liability Concerns for Filestamp Editing Tool

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, timestamp, legal

Admin at my company are wanting a timestamp editing tool to make bulk edits to some Word documents (in Windows 10) on our shared drives and I'm tasked with assessing tools from a usability and "reputation" standpoint.

The assumption being that the myriad free tools available might possibly put us "up a creek" if they mess up something with our network drives, etc. I'm both having troubling finding a non-free utility and believing that this is the best criteria for assessing value.

Does a timestamp editing tool really presents any danger?

Comment: No lawyers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your particular situation or the reasons this needs to be done, I can think of several risks that might or might not be relevant to you:

1. You are essentially destroying Metadata belonging to the document, possibly causing legal issues (e.g. was a proposal really altered after it was sent to the client? When did our rogue employee change this important document?)
2. The tool might cause backups to overwrite newer versions with older versions of the same file.
3. The tool might cause older files to be backed-up again, essentially causing a huge increase in backed-up data.
4. The tool might misbehave without you noticing it in time.